# Is there any existing model of ResNet for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm seeking the trained model of ResNet or ResNetXt for tensorflow.
Can anyone offer me a link to download it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. article, code, link to pre-trained model and the accuracy on ImageNet test set.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models